# How to change the download folder of Internet Explorer 10 under Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, internet-explorer-10

I'm using Internet Explorer 10, but every time it downloads something it tries to put it in the Downloads folder in my profile. I prefer to store those files on another drive, but I can't find any setting for it in the Internet Explorer settings.

So how do I change the default download folder for Internet Explorer?

Comment: I wonder: Was it you who couldn't figure it out easily, or ms did bad job with ui design?

Comment: Well @goldenparrot I looked through the Options and with Chrome I'm used that there's an easily accessible option to change it from there. With Internet Explorer settings are all over the place. Some are under Options, some under Windows 8 Settings (like language and autocorrect) and others are apparently context-sensitive, like the Download settings. I should note that I don't rely on the download manager, so I didn't even know there were options

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Click on the Gear and select **View downloads** or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
   [image: IE Settings Icon]
2. On the bottom left of the **View Downloads** window click **Options**.
   [image: View Downloads]
3. You'll have the option to choose a new default location.
   [image: Download Options]

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Internet Explorer 10.
2. Press CTRL + J to open View Downloads window.
3. Click on the Options link.
4. Click on the Browse button.
5. Navigate to and select(highlight) the folder that you want IE10 to
   use as the default download location, then click on the Select
   Folder button.
6. Click on OK and Close.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to open View Downloads window.
2. Click on the `Options` link.
3. Click on the `Browse` button.
4. Navigate to and select the folder that you want explorer to use as the default download location (generally default would  be downloads folder), then click on the `Select Folder` button.

Answer (score -1):

I found a way that worked for me to change the default Internet Explorer 10 download folder.

After many tries I found that the name of the new folder cannot be "Downloads". So now I use `D:\Download`. This worked for me.